# Flow error related to two overlapping workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a requirement where I have applied two workflows where one workflow equals :

(Lead: Lead StatusEQUALSCardiac Team) AND ((Lead: Cardiac ReasonEQUALSActivity Level,Can’t afford DED/OOP over 5k,Can’t afford DED/OOP under 5k,Contact never established,Difficult Personality,Geography,Looking for Suboxone Dr.,Medical Necessity,NA/AA Meeting Call,Not FMLA qualified,Not Interested) OR (Lead: Cardiac ReasonEQUALSVOB Rejected- Low Reimbursement,Refused/not supportive (family),Refusing to admit/Cold feet? (client),Other (please explain)))

Action : Update Lead owner to Shark Tank Queue

and second workflow :

(Lead: Lead OwnerNOT EQUAL TO Shark Tank) AND (Lead: Lead StatusEQUALSCardiac Team) Action : update lead status field as "active"

The first workflow is working but the second workflow gives error as flow error. Is the second workflow overlapping first one. Please let me know.

Comment: What is the error?? post the error message .

Comment: The error is :Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow
The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 301j0000000kCgp. Contact your administrator for help. 

Click here to return to the previous page.

Comment: Error is because of flow, try to troubleshoot your flow.